# Codesys matrix generation

Tags: arrays, matrix, codesys

I wanted to create a matrix of 5 rows and 2 columns.

For that i have written the code

pascal A_matrix: ARRAY [1..2, 1..5] OF REAL := [fei, fei, fei, fei, fei, 0, fei_predicted, fei_predicted, fei_predicted, fei_predicted]; // (NxN_u matrix i.e 5*2

Will the code generate in the form of 5*2 matrix?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) or the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) dirrectly. Please avoid giving code as image screenshots and use code blocks instead, it's against the code of conduct!

Comment: @Guiorgy sure will keep this in mind and would not upload from next time

Comment: Or you could edit now and replace the image with:```pascal
A_matrix: ARRAY [1..2, 1..5] OF REAL := [fei, fei, fei, fei, fei, 0, fei_predicted, fei_predicted, fei_predicted, fei_predicted]; // (N*N_u matrix i.e 5*2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the [CODESYS documentation](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.17.0/en/_cds_datatype_array/) for more information.

Your code will generate the following matrix:

| index | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fei | fei | fei | fei | fei |
| 2 | 0 | fei_predicted | fei_predicted | fei_predicted | fei_predicted |

To be more accurate, this will actually create a one dimensional array in memory and allow you to access it's elements with 2 indexes:

| indexes | 1, 1 | 1, 2 | 1, 3 | 1, 4 | 1, 5 | 2, 1 | 2, 2 | 2, 3 | 2, 4 | 2, 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| value | fei | fei | fei | fei | fei | 0 | fei_predicted | fei_predicted | fei_predicted | fei_predicted |

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I wanted to multiply this matrix with its transpose so should i create another matrix ex. A_transpose and then multiply it?

Comment: Unless you are using some special library, there's no built in way to "multiply" matrixes in CODESYS, since they aren't mathematical matrixes, but multi-dimensional arrays. You'd have to manually implement the matrix multiplication logic.